# unit testing asynchronous operation

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, asynchronous

I want to unit test a method that I have that performs and async operation:

```
 Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            // method to test and return value
            var result = LongRunningOperation();
        });
```

I stub the necessary methods etc in my unit test (written in c#) but the problem is that the async operation is not finished before I assert the test.

How can I get around this? Should I create a mock of the TaskFactory or any other tips to unit testing an async operation?

Answer (score 7):

You'd have to have some way of faking out the task creation.

If you moved the `Task.Factory.StartNew` call to some dependency (`ILongRunningOperationStarter`) then you could create an alternative implementation which used `TaskCompletionSource` to create tasks which complete exactly where you want them to.

It can get a bit hairy, but it *can* be done. I [blogged about this](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/11/25/eduasync-part-17-unit-testing/) a while ago - unit testing a method which *received* tasks to start with, which of course made things easier. It's in the context of async/await in C# 5, but the same principles apply.

If you don't want to fake out the whole of the task creation, you could replace the task factory, and control the timing that way - but I suspect that would be even hairier, to be honest.

Comment: @luviktor: Fixed, thank you. (Next time, you can always suggest the edit yourself.)

Answer (score 5):

I would propose to stub a TaskScheduler in your method with a special implementation for unit tests. You need to prepare your code to use an injected TaskScheduler:

```
 private TaskScheduler taskScheduler;

 public void OperationAsync()
 {
     Task.Factory.StartNew(
         LongRunningOperation,
         new CancellationToken(),
         TaskCreationOptions.None, 
         taskScheduler);
 }
```

In your unit test you can use the  DeterministicTaskScheduler described in [this blog post](http://svengrand.blogspot.de/2013/12/unit-testing-c-code-which-starts-new.html) to run the new task on the current thread. Your 'async' operation will be finished before you hit your first assert statement:

```
[Test]
public void ShouldExecuteLongRunningOperation()
{
    // Arrange: Inject task scheduler into class under test.
    DeterministicTaskScheduler taskScheduler = new DeterministicTaskScheduler();
    MyClass mc = new MyClass(taskScheduler);

    // Act: Let async operation create new task
    mc.OperationAsync();
    // Act:  Execute task on the current thread.
    taskScheduler.RunTasksUntilIdle();

    // Assert
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...

```
object result = null;
Task t =  Task.Factory.StartNew(() => result = LongRunningThing()); 


Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(new Task[] { t }, () => 
{
   Debug.Assert(result != null);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Set UI and background task schedulars and replace them in unit test with this one.

Below code was copied from internet, sorry for missing reference to author:

```
  public class CurrentThreadTaskScheduler : TaskScheduler
  {
    protected override void QueueTask(Task task)
    {
      TryExecuteTask(task);
    }

    protected override bool TryExecuteTaskInline(
       Task task,
       bool taskWasPreviouslyQueued)
    {
      return TryExecuteTask(task);
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<Task> GetScheduledTasks()
    {
      return Enumerable.Empty<Task>();
    }

    public override int MaximumConcurrencyLevel => 1;
  }
```

So to test code:

```
   public TaskScheduler TaskScheduler
    {
      get { return taskScheduler ?? (taskScheduler = TaskScheduler.Current); }
      set { taskScheduler = value; }
    }

    public TaskScheduler TaskSchedulerUI
    {
      get { return taskSchedulerUI ?? (taskSchedulerUI = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()); }
      set { taskSchedulerUI = value; }
    }
  public Task Update()
    {
      IsBusy = true;
      return Task.Factory.StartNew( () =>
                 {
                   LongRunningTask( );
                 }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler )
                 .ContinueWith( t => IsBusy = false, TaskSchedulerUI );
    }
```

You will write following unit test:

```
[Test]
public void WhenUpdateThenAttributeManagerUpdateShouldBeCalled()
{
  taskScheduler = new CurrentThreadTaskScheduler();
  viewModel.TaskScheduler = taskScheduler;
  viewModel.TaskSchedulerUI = taskScheduler;
  viewModel.Update();
  dataManagerMock.Verify( s => s.UpdateData( It.IsAny<DataItem>>() ) );
}
```