# Mocking HttpClient in unit tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have some issues trying to wrap my code to be used in unit tests. The issues is this. I have the interface `IHttpHandler`:

```
public interface IHttpHandler
{
    HttpClient client { get; }
}
```

And the class using it, `HttpHandler`:

```
public class HttpHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public HttpClient client
    {
        get
        {
            return new HttpClient();
        }
    }
}
```

And then the `Connection` class, which uses simpleIOC to inject the client implementation:

```
public class Connection
{
    private IHttpHandler _httpClient;

    public Connection(IHttpHandler httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }
}
```

And then I have a unit test project which has this class:

```
private IHttpHandler _httpClient;

[TestMethod]
public void TestMockConnection()
{
    var client = new Connection(_httpClient);
     
    client.doSomething();  

    // Here I want to somehow create a mock instance of the http client
    // Instead of the real one. How Should I approach this?     

}
```

Now obviously I will have methods in the `Connection` class that will retrieve data (JSON) from my backend. However, I want to write unit tests for this class, and obviously I don't want to write tests against the real back end, rather a mocked one. I have tried to google a good answer to this without great success. I can and have used Moq to mock before, but never on something like `HttpClient`. How should I approach this problem?

Comment: Exposing a `HttpClient` in your interface is where the problem is. You are forcing your client to use the `HttpClient` concrete class. Instead, you should expose an **abstraction** of the `HttpClient`.

Comment: Can you explain it a bit more in depth? How should I build the connection classes constructor because I don't want any dependancies of HttpClient in other classes the use the Connection class. For example I dont want to pass concerete HttpClient in the constructor of Connection because that would make every other class that uses Connection dependant of HttpClient?

Comment: Out of interest, what did you google? Apparently mockhttp could use some SEO improvements.

Comment: @Mike - as mentioned in my answer, there's really no need to abstract HttpClient. It's perfectly testable as-is. I have numerous projects that have backend-less test suites using this method.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Your interface exposes the concrete `HttpClient` class, therefore any classes that use this interface are tied to it, this means that it cannot be mocked.

`HttpClient` does not inherit from any interface so you will have to write your own. I suggest a **decorator-like** pattern:

```
public interface IHttpHandler
{
    HttpResponseMessage Get(string url);
    HttpResponseMessage Post(string url, HttpContent content);
    Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAsync(string url);
    Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsync(string url, HttpContent content);
}
```

And your class will look like this:

```
public class HttpClientHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    private HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();

    public HttpResponseMessage Get(string url)
    {
        return GetAsync(url).Result;
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage Post(string url, HttpContent content)
    {
        return PostAsync(url, content).Result;
    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAsync(string url)
    {
        return await _client.GetAsync(url);
    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsync(string url, HttpContent content)
    {
        return await _client.PostAsync(url, content);
    }
}
```

The point in all of this is that `HttpClientHandler` creates its own `HttpClient`, you could then of course create multiple classes that implement `IHttpHandler` in different ways.

The main issue with this approach is that you are effectively writing a class that just calls methods in another class, however you could create a class that **inherits** from `HttpClient` (See **Nkosi's example**, it's a much better approach than mine). Life would be much easier if `HttpClient` had an interface that you could mock, unfortunately it does not.

This example is **not** the golden ticket however. `IHttpHandler` still relies on `HttpResponseMessage`, which belongs to `System.Net.Http` namespace, therefore if you do need other implementations other than `HttpClient`, you will have to perform some kind of mapping to convert their responses into `HttpResponseMessage` objects. This of course is only a problem **if you need to use multiple implementations** of `IHttpHandler` but it doesn't look like you do so it's not the end of the world, but it's something to think about.

Anyway, you can simply mock `IHttpHandler` without having to worry about the concrete `HttpClient` class as it has been abstracted away.

I recommend testing the **non-async** methods, as these still call the asynchronous methods but without the hassle of having to worry about unit testing asynchronous methods, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556350/unit-testing-asynchronous-operation)

Comment: This does indeed answer my question. Nkosis answer is also correct so I am not sure which I should accept as answer, but I will go with this one. Thank you both for the effort

Comment: Worth noting that the main difference between this answer and Nkosi's is this is a much thinner abstraction. Thin is probably good for a [humble object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324049/what-is-the-humble-object-pattern-and-when-is-it-useful)

Comment: Please add a note that this should be registered as a Singleton. Creating lots of HttpClient is not good - https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Answer (score 411):

`HttpClient`'s extensibility lies in the `HttpMessageHandler` passed to the constructor. Its intent is to allow platform specific implementations, but you can also mock it. There's no need to create a decorator wrapper for `HttpClient`.

If you'd prefer a DSL to using Moq, I have a library up on GitHub/Nuget that makes things a little easier: https://github.com/richardszalay/mockhttp

The [Nuget Package RichardSzalay.MockHttp is available here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RichardSzalay.MockHttp/).

```
var mockHttp = new MockHttpMessageHandler();

// Setup a respond for the user api (including a wildcard in the URL)
mockHttp.When("http://localhost/api/user/*")
        .Respond("application/json", "{'name' : 'Test McGee'}"); // Respond with JSON

// Inject the handler or client into your application code
var client = new HttpClient(mockHttp);

var response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost/api/user/1234");
// or without async: var response = client.GetAsync("http://localhost/api/user/1234").Result;

var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

// No network connection required
Console.Write(json); // {'name' : 'Test McGee'}
```

Comment: So I would just pass MockHttpMessageHandler as the messagehandler Httphandler class? Or how have you implemented it in your own projects

Comment: Yes you pass the MockHttpMessageHandler to the HttpClient constructor and then you pass that HttpClient to your component before testing it.

Comment: But your component can also depend on HttpMessageHandler itself and create an HttpClient. Or if injection isn't possible you could take a look at registering the mock via `HttpClientFactory` (though  I've never used that last method myself).

Comment: For people who don't want to deal with injecting the client but still want easy testability, it's trivial to achieve. Just replace `var client = new HttpClient()` with `var client = ClientFactory()` and setup a field `internal static Func<HttpClient> ClientFactory = () => new HttpClient();` and at the test level you can rewrite this field.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic you are suggesting a form of service location to replace injection. Service location is a well-known anti-pattern so imho injection is preferrable.

Comment: @MarioDS service location (SL) is a fine pattern. It is absolutely not an anti-pattern, in fact service location is one of the most powerful patterns in existence. Like all patterns it can be used wrongly, given the dynamicism that SL provides it can be unwieldy if applied poorly. Pretty much every single IOC Container depends on the SL pattern. I've held this position consistently for over half a decade http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/ Seemann is allowed to be wrong.

Comment: @MarioDS and regardless, you shouldn't be injecting a HttpClient **instance** at all. If you are dead set on using constructer injection for this then you should be injecting a `HttpClientFactory` as in `Func<HttpClient>`.  Given I view HttpClient as purely an implementation detail and not a dependency, i'll use statics just as I illustrated above. I'm entirely fine with tests manipulating internals. If  I care about pure-ism i'll stand up full servers and test live code paths. Using any kind of mock means you accept approximation of behavior not actual behavior.

Comment: In a real world scenario my class will have a HttpClientFactory  that specifies external resource specific details, could be as simple as hostname. Allowing all my instance calls to specify relative paths. This also can wrap up details like authentication tokens to a specific API. This kind of stuff is highly specific and has no purpose being inside a container and having to resolve the correct flavor of HttpClient for a external resource access class.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic as an update, it's now explicitly recommended that you use a single instance of HttpClient

Comment: This strategy in Moq-land here: https://gingter.org/2018/07/26/how-to-mock-httpclient-in-your-net-c-unit-tests/

Comment: Much better solution than createing an interface since it reduces the amount of boiler plate code dramatically. Go for this solution!

Comment: I actually think in situations where you're forced to write a fake HttpMessageHandler (depending on the mocking framework you're using), this ends up with far more cluttered tests than simply wrapping HttpClient.

Comment: There's also this library https://github.com/skwasjer/MockHttp which is similar to @RichardSzalay 's.

Comment: Unfortunately @RichardSzalay's package doesn't appear to be fully functional anymore, I tried a netcore3.0 nunit3 test project and was unable to get WithHeaders and WithFormData to work properly.

Comment: @bobbyg603 Please log a bug at the repository. I use the library myself in several .NET Core 3 + 6 projects.

Comment: You are fine to inject an instance of `HttpClient` IF you are letting Dependency Injection handle the lifetime. This is typically done via `IServiceCollection.AddHttpClient`. DI will use `HttpClientFactory` under the covers and dispose of the `HttpClient` appropriately.

Comment: @RichardSzalay What do you mean by DSL?

Comment: How would you test a class that has a private static `HttpClient`? How would you mock it in that situation?

Comment: @DavidKlempfner you'd need a way of injecting the mock HttpClient into the instance, either via constructor or an internal static method or similar.

Comment: This is brilliant, works perfectly for setting up mock `IHttpClientFactory` as well.

Answer (score 118):

I agree with some of the other answers that the best approach is to mock the HttpMessageHandler inside HttpClient, rather than wrap HttpClient.  This answer is unique in that it still injects HttpClient, allowing it to be a singleton or managed with dependency injection.

> HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once and re-used throughout
> the life of an application.

([Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client#create-and-initialize-httpclient)).

Mocking HttpMessageHandler can be a little tricky because SendAsync is protected.  Here's a complete example, using xunit and Moq.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Moq;
using Moq.Protected;
using Xunit;
// Use nuget to install xunit and Moq

namespace MockHttpClient {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var analyzer = new SiteAnalyzer(Client);
            var size = analyzer.GetContentSize("http://microsoft.com").Result;
            Console.WriteLine($"Size: {size}");
        }

        private static readonly HttpClient Client = new HttpClient(); // Singleton
    }

    public class SiteAnalyzer {
        public SiteAnalyzer(HttpClient httpClient) {
            _httpClient = httpClient;
        }

        public async Task<int> GetContentSize(string uri)
        {
            var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync( uri );
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return content.Length;
        }

        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    }

    public class SiteAnalyzerTests {
        [Fact]
        public async void GetContentSizeReturnsCorrectLength() {
            // Arrange
            const string testContent = "test content";
            var mockMessageHandler = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>();
            mockMessageHandler.Protected()
                .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>("SendAsync", ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(), ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
                .ReturnsAsync(new HttpResponseMessage {
                    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
                    Content = new StringContent(testContent)
                });
            var underTest = new SiteAnalyzer(new HttpClient(mockMessageHandler.Object));

            // Act
            var result = await underTest.GetContentSize("http://anyurl");

            // Assert
            Assert.Equal(testContent.Length, result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I really liked this. The `mockMessageHandler.Protected()` was the killer. Thanks for this example. It allows to write the test without modifying the source at all.

Comment: FYI, Moq 4.8 supports strongly typed mocking of protected members - https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart

Comment: This looks great. Also Moq supports ReturnsAsync so the code would look like `.ReturnsAsync(new HttpResponseMessage {StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK, Content = new StringContent(testContent)})`

Comment: Is there any way to verify that "SandAsync" was called with some parameters? I've tried to use ...Protected().Verify(...), but looks like it does not work with async methods.

Comment: mockHttpMessageHandler.Protected().Verify(METHOD_SENDASYNC, Times.Once(), ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(), ItExpr.IsAny<System.Threading.CancellationToken>());

Unfortunately, it is working only some times. Async method ReturnsAsync() is being called strangely such that the state of test class variables are affected between various test cases.

Comment: @Rroman use a callback to capture the input parameters.  The trick with async methods is that you have to return something from them:
.Setup(....).Callback(...).Returns(Task.FromResult(...))

Comment: @Rroman you can pass an expression to verify that it was called with an object matching and expression https://gingter.org/2018/07/26/how-to-mock-httpclient-in-your-net-c-unit-tests/

Answer (score 38):

Here's a simple solution, which worked well for me.

Using the moq mocking library.

```
// ARRANGE
var handlerMock = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>(MockBehavior.Strict);
handlerMock
   .Protected()
   // Setup the PROTECTED method to mock
   .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>(
      "SendAsync",
      ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(),
      ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>()
   )
   // prepare the expected response of the mocked http call
   .ReturnsAsync(new HttpResponseMessage()
   {
      StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
      Content = new StringContent("[{'id':1,'value':'1'}]"),
   })
   .Verifiable();

// use real http client with mocked handler here
var httpClient = new HttpClient(handlerMock.Object)
{
   BaseAddress = new Uri("http://test.com/"),
};

var subjectUnderTest = new MyTestClass(httpClient);

// ACT
var result = await subjectUnderTest
   .GetSomethingRemoteAsync('api/test/whatever');

// ASSERT
result.Should().NotBeNull(); // this is fluent assertions here...
result.Id.Should().Be(1);

// also check the 'http' call was like we expected it
var expectedUri = new Uri("http://test.com/api/test/whatever");

handlerMock.Protected().Verify(
   "SendAsync",
   Times.Exactly(1), // we expected a single external request
   ItExpr.Is<HttpRequestMessage>(req =>
      req.Method == HttpMethod.Get  // we expected a GET request
      && req.RequestUri == expectedUri // to this uri
   ),
   ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>()
);
```

Source: https://gingter.org/2018/07/26/how-to-mock-httpclient-in-your-net-c-unit-tests/

Comment: I've also used this sucessfully. I prefer this to dfragging in yet anohter nuget dependency and you actually learn a bit more about what's happening under the hood too. Nice thing is most of the methods end up using `SendAsync` anyway so no extra setup required.

Answer (score 33):

This is a common question, and I was heavily on the side wanting the ability to mock HttpClient, but I think I finally came to the realization that you shouldn't be mocking HttpClient. It seems logical to do so, but I think we've been brainwashed by things we see in open source libraries.

We often see "Clients" out there that we mock in our code so that we can test in isolation, so we automatically try to apply the same principle to HttpClient. HttpClient actually does a lot; you can think of it as a manager for HttpMessageHandler, so you don't wanna mock that, and that's why it *still* doesn't have an interface. The part that you're really interested in for unit testing, or designing your services, even, is the HttpMessageHandler since that is what returns the response, and you *can* mock that.

It's also worth pointing out that you should probably start treating HttpClient like a bigger deal. For example: Keep your instatiating of new HttpClients to a minimum. Reuse them, they're designed to be reused and use a crap ton less resources if you do. If you start treating it like a bigger deal, it'll feel much more wrong wanting to mock it and now the message handler will start to be the thing that you're injecting, not the client.

In other words, design your dependencies around the handler instead of the client. Even better, abstract "services" that use HttpClient which allow you to inject a handler, and use that as your injectable dependency instead. In fact, HttpClientFactor (which you should be using) is designed with extensions to inject the message handlers. Then in your tests, you can fake the handler to control the response for setting up your tests.

Wrapping HttpClient is an insane waste of time.

Update:
See Joshua Dooms's example. It's exactly what I'm recommending.

Comment: So while I see your point I wonder, is that not the point of the seperation? An interface defines what *something* *should* do not what it does do and it hides all the internal details (simple or complex). With this in mind I think HttpClient should have an interface so that I don't have to build something that looks like it (an interface and/or a wrapper class) or have to talk to a mock server (more memory and other resources). Just my thoughts though..

Comment: @JoshuaG no not really. HttpClient is actually a fairly low-level, protocol implementation. It would be like mocking your OS (to put it hyperbolically). The responsibility you're trying to separate wouldn't occur at that level which is why the message handler is there and injectable in the first place. That's the component that exists conceptually in the developer space. As a developer your developing the handling of messages (which is the part you wanna mock), not network protocols. If you want to mock network protocols then... I have no idea why someone would do that

Comment: In other words, if you had a need to mock handshakes and acks and dns resolution, etc, then I could see why you would need to mock httpclient, but that's a very very uncommon practice. If you need to mock behavior based on http messages (codes, headers, payloads, simulating timeouts, etc) - thats the message handler, not the client.

Answer (score 29):

There are several different approaches to mock an `HttpClient`.  Here are a few that I've done some POC's on using `xUnit` before deciding on a single solution (`Moq.Contrib.HttpClient`). Note that there are many more abilities to each framework than what I show below; I kept each example succinct for clarity.

## Moq (by itself)

This is relatively straightforward if you are familiar with using the [Moq](https://github.com/moq/moq4) framework. The "trick" is to mock the `HttpMessageHandler` inside of the `HttpClient` - not the `HttpClient` itself. NOTE: It is good practice to use `MockBehavior.Strict` in the mock so that you are alerted to any calls that you have not explicitly mocked-out and were expecting.

## RichardSzalay.MockHttp

[RichardSzalay.MockHttp](https://github.com/richardszalay/mockhttp) is another popular solution. I've used this in the past but found it slightly more cumbersome that `Moq.Contrib.HttpClient`. There are two different patterns that can be used here. Richard describes when to use one vs the other [here](https://github.com/richardszalay/mockhttp#when-backend-definitions-vs-expect-request-expectations).

## Moq.Contrib.HttpClient

Like the solution for using `Moq` by itself, this is straightforward if you are familiar with using the [Moq](https://github.com/moq/moq4) framework. I found this solution to be slightly more direct with less code. This is the solution I opted to use. Note that this solution requires a separate Nuget from `Moq` itself - [Moq.Contrib.HttpClient](https://github.com/maxkagamine/Moq.Contrib.HttpClient)

## WireMock.Net

A newcomer to the game, [WireMock.net](https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net/wiki/Using-WireMock-in-UnitTests) is gaining popularity. This would be a reasonable solution instead of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost` if you are writing Integration Tests where calls to the endpoint are actually made instead of being mocked. I thought this would be my pick at first but decided against it for two reasons:

1. it does actually open ports to facilitate the test. Since I've had to fix [port-exhaustion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/http/httpclient-guidelines) issues from improper usage of `HttpClient` in the past, I decided to pass on this solution as I wasn't sure how well it would scale across a large codebase with many unit tests running in parallel.
2. The urls used must be resolvable (actual legit urls). If you want the simplicity of not caring about a "real" url (just that the url you expected was actually called) then this may not be for you.

## Example

Given the following simplistic/contrived code, here is how you would write each test.

```
public class ClassUnderTest
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    private const string Url = "https://myurl";

    public ClassUnderTest(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public async Task<Person> GetPersonAsync(int id)
    {
        var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync($"{Url}?id={id}");
        return await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<Person>();
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

## Moq (by itself)

```
[Fact]
public async Task JustMoq()
{
    //arrange
    const int personId = 1;
    var mockHandler = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    var dto = new Person { Id = personId, Name = "Dave", Age = 42 };
    var mockResponse = new HttpResponseMessage
    {
        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
        Content = JsonContent.Create<Person>(dto)
    };

    mockHandler
        .Protected()
        .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>(
            "SendAsync",
            ItExpr.Is<HttpRequestMessage>(m => m.Method == HttpMethod.Get),
            ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
        .ReturnsAsync(mockResponse);

    // Inject the handler or client into your application code
    var httpClient = new HttpClient(mockHandler.Object);
    var sut = new ClassUnderTest(httpClient);

    //act
    var actual = await sut.GetPersonAsync(personId);

    //assert
    Assert.NotNull(actual);
    mockHandler.Protected().Verify(
        "SendAsync",
        Times.Exactly(1),
        ItExpr.Is<HttpRequestMessage>(m => m.Method == HttpMethod.Get),
        ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>());
}
```

## RichardSzalay.MockHttp (using BackendDefinition pattern)

```
[Fact]
public async Task RichardSzalayMockHttpUsingBackendDefinition()
{
    //arrange
    const int personId = 1;
    using var mockHandler = new MockHttpMessageHandler();
    var dto = new Person { Id = personId, Name = "Dave", Age = 42 };
    var mockResponse = new HttpResponseMessage
    {
        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
        Content = JsonContent.Create<Person>(dto)
    };

    var mockedRequest = mockHandler.When(HttpMethod.Get, "https://myurl?id=1")
        .Respond(mockResponse.StatusCode, mockResponse.Content);

    // Inject the handler or client into your application code
    var httpClient = mockHandler.ToHttpClient();
    var sut = new ClassUnderTest(httpClient);

    //act
    var actual = await sut.GetPersonAsync(personId);

    //assert
    Assert.NotNull(actual);
    Assert.Equivalent(dto, actual);
    Assert.Equal(1, mockHandler.GetMatchCount(mockedRequest));
    mockHandler.VerifyNoOutstandingRequest();
}
```

## RichardSzalay.MockHttp (using RequestExpectation pattern)

```
[Fact]
public async Task RichardSzalayMockHttpUsingRequestExpectation()
{
    //arrange
    const int personId = 1;
    using var mockHandler = new MockHttpMessageHandler();
    var dto = new Person { Id = personId, Name = "Dave", Age = 42 };
    var mockResponse = new HttpResponseMessage
    {
        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
        Content = JsonContent.Create<Person>(dto)
    };

    var mockedRequest = mockHandler.Expect(HttpMethod.Get, "https://myurl")
        .WithExactQueryString($"id={personId}")
        .Respond(mockResponse.StatusCode, mockResponse.Content);

    // Inject the handler or client into your application code
    var httpClient = mockHandler.ToHttpClient();
    var sut = new ClassUnderTest(httpClient);

    //act
    var actual = await sut.GetPersonAsync(personId);

    //assert
    Assert.NotNull(actual);
    Assert.Equivalent(dto, actual);
    Assert.Equal(1, mockHandler.GetMatchCount(mockedRequest));
    mockHandler.VerifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
}
```

## Moq.Contrib.HttpClient

```
[Fact]
public async Task UsingMoqContribHttpClient()
{
    //arrange
    const int personId = 1;
    var mockHandler = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    var dto = new Person { Id = personId, Name = "Dave", Age = 42 };
    var mockUrl = $"https://myurl?id={personId}";
    var mockResponse = mockHandler.SetupRequest(HttpMethod.Get, mockUrl)
        .ReturnsJsonResponse<Person>(HttpStatusCode.OK, dto);

    // Inject the handler or client into your application code
    var httpClient = mockHandler.CreateClient();
    var sut = new ClassUnderTest(httpClient);

    //act
    var actual = await sut.GetPersonAsync(personId);

    //assert
    Assert.NotNull(actual);
    Assert.Equivalent(dto, actual);
    mockHandler.VerifyRequest(HttpMethod.Get, mockUrl, Times.Once());
}
```

## WireMock.NET

```
public class TestClass : IDisposable
{
    private WireMockServer _server;

    public TestClass()
    {
        _server = WireMockServer.Start();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _server.Stop();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task UsingWireMock()
    {
        //arrange
        const int personId = 1;
        var dto = new Person { Id = personId, Name = "Dave", Age = 42 };
        var mockUrl = $"https://myurl?id={personId}";

        _server.Given(
            Request.Create()
                .WithPath("/"))
            .RespondWith(
                Response.Create()
                    .WithStatusCode(200)
                    .WithHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .WithBodyAsJson(dto));

        // Inject the handler or client into your application code
        var httpClient = _server.CreateClient();
        var sut = new ClassUnderTest(httpClient);

        //act
        var actual = await sut.GetPersonAsync(personId);

        //assert
        Assert.NotNull(actual);
        Assert.Equivalent(dto, actual);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 26):

Building on the other answers, I suggest this code, which does not have any outside dependencies:

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTestClass
{
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task MyTestMethod()
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient(new MockHttpMessageHandler());

        var content = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://some.fake.url");

        Assert.AreEqual("Content as string", content);
    }
}

public class MockHttpMessageHandler : HttpMessageHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var responseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new StringContent("Content as string")
        };

        return await Task.FromResult(responseMessage);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are effectively testing your mock. The real power of a mock is that you can set expectations and alter it's behaviour in each test. The fact that you have to implement some `HttpMessageHandler` yourself makes that next to impossible - and you have to because the methods are `protected internal`.

Comment: @MarioDS I think the point is that you can mock the HTTP response so you can test the rest of the code.  If you inject a factory that gets the HttpClient, then in tests you can supply this HttpClient.

Answer (score 22):

As also mentioned in the comments you need to **abstract** away the `HttpClient` so as not to be coupled to it. I've done something similar in the past. I'll try to adapt what I did with what you are trying to do.

First look at the `HttpClient` class and decided on what functionality it provided that would be needed.

Here is a possibility:

```
public interface IHttpClient {
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<T> DeleteAsync<T>(string uri) where T : class;
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<T> DeleteAsync<T>(Uri uri) where T : class;
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string uri) where T : class;
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<T> GetAsync<T>(Uri uri) where T : class;
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<T> PostAsync<T>(string uri, object package);
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<T> PostAsync<T>(Uri uri, object package);
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<T> PutAsync<T>(string uri, object package);
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<T> PutAsync<T>(Uri uri, object package);
}
```

Again as stated before this was for particular purposes. I completely abstracted away most dependencies to anything dealing with `HttpClient` and focused on what I wanted returned. You should evaluate how you want to abstract the `HttpClient` to provide only the necessary functionality you want.

This will now allow you to mock only what is needed to be tested.

I would even recommend doing away with `IHttpHandler` completely and use the `HttpClient` abstraction `IHttpClient`. But I'm just not picking as you can replace the body of your handler interface with the members of the abstracted client.

An implementation of the `IHttpClient` can then be used to wrapp/adapt a real/concrete `HttpClient` or any other object for that matter, that can be used to make HTTP requests as what you really wanted was a service that provided that functionality as apposed to `HttpClient` specifically. Using the abstraction is a clean (My opinion) and SOLID approach and can make your code more maintainable if you need to switch out the underlying client for something else as the framework changes.

Here is a snippet of how an implementation could be done.

```
/// <summary>
/// HTTP Client adaptor wraps a <see cref="System.Net.Http.HttpClient"/> 
/// that contains a reference to <see cref="ConfigurableMessageHandler"/>
/// </summary>
public sealed class HttpClientAdaptor : IHttpClient {
    HttpClient httpClient;

    public HttpClientAdaptor(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory) {
        httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateHttpClient(**Custom configurations**);
    }

    //...other code

     /// <summary>
    ///  Send a GET request to the specified Uri as an asynchronous operation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Response type</typeparam>
    /// <param name="uri">The Uri the request is sent to</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<T> GetAsync<T>(Uri uri) where T : class {
        var result = default(T);
        //Try to get content as T
        try {
            //send request and get the response
            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri).ConfigureAwait(false);
            //if there is content in response to deserialize
            if (response.Content.Headers.ContentLength.GetValueOrDefault() > 0) {
                //get the content
                string responseBodyAsText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                //desrialize it
                result = deserializeJsonToObject<T>(responseBodyAsText);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.Error(ex);
        }
        return result;
    }

    //...other code
}
```

As you can see in the above example, a lot of the heavy lifting usually associated with using `HttpClient` is hidden behind the abstraction.

You connection class can then be inject with the abstracted client

```
public class Connection
{
    private IHttpClient _httpClient;

    public Connection(IHttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }
}
```

Your test can then mock what is needed for your SUT

```
private IHttpClient _httpClient;

[TestMethod]
public void TestMockConnection()
{
    SomeModelObject model = new SomeModelObject();
    var httpClientMock = new Mock<IHttpClient>();
    httpClientMock.Setup(c => c.GetAsync<SomeModelObject>(It.IsAny<string>()))
        .Returns(() => Task.FromResult(model));

    _httpClient = httpClientMock.Object;

    var client = new Connection(_httpClient);

    // Assuming doSomething uses the client to make
    // a request for a model of type SomeModelObject
    client.doSomething();  
}
```

Comment: THIS is the answer. An abstraction above `HttpClient` and an adapter to create your specific instance using `HttpClientFactory`. Doing this makes testing the logic beyond the HTTP request trivial, which is the goal here.

Answer (score 19):

I think the issue is that you've got it just a little upside down.

```
public class AuroraClient : IAuroraClient
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public AuroraClient() : this(new HttpClientHandler())
    {
    }

    public AuroraClient(HttpMessageHandler messageHandler)
    {
        _client = new HttpClient(messageHandler);
    }
}
```

If you look at the class above, I think this is what you want.  Microsoft recommends keeping the client alive for optimal performance, so this type of structure allows you to do that. Also the HttpMessageHandler is an abstract class and therefore mockable. Your test method would then look like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    // Arrange
    var mockMessageHandler = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>();
    // Set up your mock behavior here
    var auroraClient = new AuroraClient(mockMessageHandler.Object);
    // Act
    // Assert
}
```

This allows you to test your logic while mocking the HttpClient's behavior.

Sorry guys, after writing this and trying it myself, I realized that you can't mock the protected methods on the HttpMessageHandler.  I subsequently added the following code to allow for injection of a proper mock.

```
public interface IMockHttpMessageHandler
{
    Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}

public class MockHttpMessageHandler : HttpMessageHandler
{
    private readonly IMockHttpMessageHandler _realMockHandler;

    public MockHttpMessageHandler(IMockHttpMessageHandler realMockHandler)
    {
        _realMockHandler = realMockHandler;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return await _realMockHandler.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

The tests written with this then look something like the following:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task GetProductsReturnsDeserializedXmlXopData()
{
    // Arrange
    var mockMessageHandler = new Mock<IMockHttpMessageHandler>();
    // Set up Mock behavior here.
    var client = new AuroraClient(new MockHttpMessageHandler(mockMessageHandler.Object));
    // Act
    // Assert
}
```

Comment: The first part of this answer is correct, use HttpMessageHandler.  There's a nice blog with samples here, https://gingter.org/2018/07/26/how-to-mock-httpclient-in-your-net-c-unit-tests/.  Moq (now) does let you mock and test protected methods

Answer (score 10):

One alternative would be to setup a stub HTTP server that returns canned responses based on pattern matching the request url, meaning you test real HTTP requests not mocks. Historically this would have taken significant develoment effort and would have been far to slow to be considered for unit testing, however OSS library [WireMock.net](https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net) is easy to use and fast enough to be run with lots of tests so may be worth considering. Setup is a few lines of code:

```
var server = FluentMockServer.Start();
server.Given(
      Request.Create()
      .WithPath("/some/thing").UsingGet()
   )
   .RespondWith(
       Response.Create()
       .WithStatusCode(200)
       .WithHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
       .WithBody("{'attr':'value'}")
   );
```

You can find a more details and [guidance on using wiremock in tests here.](https://alastaircrabtree.com/stubbing-your-way-to-automated-e2e-testing-api-first-with-wiremock/)

Answer (score 10):

One of my colleagues noticed that most of the `HttpClient` methods all call `SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)` under the hood, which is a virtual method off of `HttpMessageInvoker`:

So by far the easiest way to mock out `HttpClient` was to simply mock that particular method:

```
var mockClient = new Mock<HttpClient>();
mockClient.Setup(client => client.SendAsync(It.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).ReturnsAsync(_mockResponse.Object);
```

and your code can call most (but not all) of the `HttpClient` class methods, including a regular

```
httpClient.SendAsync(req)
```

Check here to confirm
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs

Comment: This doesn't work for any code that calls `SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage)` directly though.  If you can modify your code not to use this convenience function, then mocking HttpClient directly by overriding `SendAsync` is actually the cleanest solution I've found.

Comment: It used to be this way earlier, but I think with current changes it would be far easier to mock the internal HttpHandler and add to services and set up the mock how it Returns SendAsync method.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not convinced by many of the answers.

First of all, imagine you want to unit test a method that uses `HttpClient`. You should not instantiate `HttpClient` directly in your implementation. You should inject a factory with the responsibility of providing an instance of `HttpClient` for you. That way you can mock later on that factory and return whichever `HttpClient` you want (e.g: a mock `HttpClient` and not the real one).

So, you would have a factory like the following:

```
public interface IHttpClientFactory
{
    HttpClient Create();
}
```

And an implementation:

```
public class HttpClientFactory
    : IHttpClientFactory
{
    public HttpClient Create()
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        return httpClient;
    }
}
```

Of course you would need to register in your IoC Container this implementation. If you use Autofac it would be something like:

```
builder
    .RegisterType<IHttpClientFactory>()
    .As<HttpClientFactory>()
    .SingleInstance();
```

Now you would have a proper and testeable implementation. Imagine that your method is something like:

```
public class MyHttpClient
    : IMyHttpClient
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

    public SalesOrderHttpClient(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    }

    public async Task<string> PostAsync(Uri uri, string content)
    {
        using (var client = _httpClientFactory.Create())
        {
            var clientAddress = uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(clientAddress);
            var content = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var uriAbsolutePath = uri.AbsolutePath;
            var response = await client.PostAsync(uriAbsolutePath, content);
            var responseJson = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            return responseJson;
        }
    }
}
```

Now the testing part. `HttpClient` extends `HttpMessageHandler`, which is abstract. Let's create a "mock" of `HttpMessageHandler` that accepts a delegate so that when we use the mock we can also setup each behaviour for each test.

```
public class MockHttpMessageHandler 
    : HttpMessageHandler
{
    private readonly Func<HttpRequestMessage, CancellationToken, Task<HttpResponseMessage>> _sendAsyncFunc;

    public MockHttpMessageHandler(Func<HttpRequestMessage, CancellationToken, Task<HttpResponseMessage>> sendAsyncFunc)
    {
        _sendAsyncFunc = sendAsyncFunc;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return await _sendAsyncFunc.Invoke(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

And now, and with the help of Moq (and FluentAssertions, a library that makes unit tests more readable), we have everything needed to unit test our method PostAsync that uses `HttpClient`

```
public static class PostAsyncTests
{
    public class Given_A_Uri_And_A_JsonMessage_When_Posting_Async
        : Given_WhenAsync_Then_Test
    {
        private SalesOrderHttpClient _sut;
        private Uri _uri;
        private string _content;
        private string _expectedResult;
        private string _result;

        protected override void Given()
        {
            _uri = new Uri("http://test.com/api/resources");
            _content = "{\"foo\": \"bar\"}";
            _expectedResult = "{\"result\": \"ok\"}";

            var httpClientFactoryMock = new Mock<IHttpClientFactory>();
            var messageHandlerMock =
                new MockHttpMessageHandler((request, cancellation) =>
                {
                    var responseMessage =
                        new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Created)
                        {
                            Content = new StringContent("{\"result\": \"ok\"}")
                        };

                    var result = Task.FromResult(responseMessage);
                    return result;
                });

            var httpClient = new HttpClient(messageHandlerMock);
            httpClientFactoryMock
                .Setup(x => x.Create())
                .Returns(httpClient);

            var httpClientFactory = httpClientFactoryMock.Object;

            _sut = new SalesOrderHttpClient(httpClientFactory);
        }

        protected override async Task WhenAsync()
        {
            _result = await _sut.PostAsync(_uri, _content);
        }


        [Fact]
        public void Then_It_Should_Return_A_Valid_JsonMessage()
        {
            _result.Should().BeEquivalentTo(_expectedResult);
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously this test is silly, and we're really testing our mock. But you get the idea. You should test meaningful logic depending on your implementation such as..

- if the code status of the response is not 201, should it throw an exception?
- if the response text cannot be parsed, what should happen?
- etc.

The purpose of this answer was to test something that uses HttpClient and this is a nice clean way to do so.

---

**UPDATE**
Lately I use an http builder in my tests where I can easily inject the json response I expect.

```
public class HttpClientBuilder
{
    private HttpMessageHandler _httpMessageHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
    
    public HttpClientBuilder WithJsonResponse(HttpStatusCode httpStatusCode, string json, string contentType = "application/json")
    {
        var mockHttpMessageHandler =
            new MockHttpMessageHandler(
                (request, cancellation) =>
                {
                    var responseMessage =
                        new HttpResponseMessage(httpStatusCode)
                        {
                            Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, contentType)
                        };
                    var result = Task.FromResult(responseMessage);
                    return result;
                });
        _httpMessageHandler = mockHttpMessageHandler;
        return this;
    }

    public HttpClient Build()
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient(_httpMessageHandler);
        return httpClient;
    }
}

class MockHttpMessageHandler 
    : HttpMessageHandler
{
    private readonly Func<HttpRequestMessage, CancellationToken, Task<HttpResponseMessage>> _sendAsyncFunc;

    public MockHttpMessageHandler(Func<HttpRequestMessage, CancellationToken, Task<HttpResponseMessage>> sendAsyncFunc)
    {
        _sendAsyncFunc = sendAsyncFunc;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return await _sendAsyncFunc.Invoke(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

so, as long as I have the HttpClient behind an abstraction like `IHttpClientFactory`, as I've suggested above, in my tests I can do something like

```
var httpClientFactoryMock = new Mock<IHttpClientFactory>();
var jsonResponse = "{\"hello world\"}";
var httpClient = 
  new HttpClientBuilder()
    .WithJsonResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, jsonResponse)
    .Build();
                
httpClientFactoryMock
  .Setup(x => x.Create())
  .Returns(httpClient);
var httpClientFactory = httpClientFactoryMock.Object;
```

and then use that httpClientFactory.

Answer (score 9):

Microsoft now offers the alternative to use a `IHttpClientFactory` instead of directly using `HttpClient`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Example Mock with request that returns expected result:

```
private LoginController GetLoginController()
{
    var expected = "Hello world";
    var mockFactory = new Mock<IHttpClientFactory>();

    var mockMessageHandler = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>();
    mockMessageHandler.Protected()
        .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>("SendAsync", ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(), ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
        .ReturnsAsync(new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
            Content = new StringContent(expected)
        });

    var httpClient = new HttpClient(mockMessageHandler.Object);

    mockFactory.Setup(_ => _.CreateClient(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(httpClient);

    var logger = Mock.Of<ILogger<LoginController>>();

    var controller = new LoginController(logger, mockFactory.Object);

    return controller;
}
```

Source:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66256132/3850405

Comment: Microsoft also suggests using named and type HttpClients, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests

That statement doesn't support your answer

Comment: If you vote down please say. Hard to improve answers otherwise

Comment: @BhanuChhabra Microsoft says "There are several ways IHttpClientFactory can be used in an app: Basic usage, Named clients, Typed clients and Generated clients". This shows a Basic usage but can be used as a template for other implementations as well.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-6.0#consumption-patterns

Comment: at the time I commented on this post, the idea was to counter the point that Microsoft doesn't recommend a single approach, it has listed multiple approaches, and as a developer, you need to find the best fit.

Comment: @BhanuChhabra Very true, reformulated my answer.

Answer (score 9):

***DO NOT*** have a wrapper that creates a new instance of HttpClient. If you do that, you will run out of sockets at runtime (even though you are disposing the HttpClient object).

If using MOQ, the correct way to do this is to add `using Moq.Protected;` to your test and then write code like the following:

```cs
var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    Content = new StringContent("It worked!")
};
var mockHttpMessageHandler = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>();
mockHttpMessageHandler
    .Protected()
    .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>(
        "SendAsync",
        ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(),
        ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
    .ReturnsAsync(() => response);


var httpClient = new HttpClient(mockHttpMessageHandler.Object);
```

Answer (score 6):

Joining the party a bit late, but I like using wiremocking (https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net) whenever possible in the integrationtest of a dotnet core microservice with downstream REST dependencies.

By implementing a TestHttpClientFactory extending the IHttpClientFactory we can override the method

HttpClient CreateClient(string name)

So when using the named clients within your app you are in control of returning a HttpClient wired to your wiremock.

The good thing about this approach is that you are not changing anything within the application you are testing, and enables course integration tests doing an actual REST request to your service and mocking the json (or whatever) the actual downstream request should return. This leads to concise tests and as little mocking as possible in your application.

```
    public class TestHttpClientFactory : IHttpClientFactory 
{
    public HttpClient CreateClient(string name)
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri(G.Config.Get<string>($"App:Endpoints:{name}"))
            // G.Config is our singleton config access, so the endpoint 
            // to the running wiremock is used in the test
        };
        return httpClient;
    }
}
```

and

```
// in bootstrap of your Microservice
IHttpClientFactory factory = new TestHttpClientFactory();
container.Register<IHttpClientFactory>(factory);
```

Comment: This kind of test is particularly helpful for BFFs and other api that do lot of mapping of API calls. As often the error might easily be caught in the produced json, rather than trying to map Java/C# code.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind running your own http server, you can try [Xim](https://github.com/tonto7973/xim/wiki/Xim-Http-Api-Simulator). It's as easy as this:

```cs
using Xim.Simulators.Api;
```

```cs
[Test]
public async Task TestHttpGetMethod()
{
    using var simulation = Simulation.Create();
    using var api = simulation
        .AddApi()
        .AddHandler("GET /books/1234", ApiResponse.Ok())
        .Build();
    await api.StartAsync();
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();

    var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, $"{api.Location}/books/1234"));

    Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
    Assert.IsTrue(api.ReceivedApiCalls.Any(call => call.Action == "GET /books/1234"));
}
```

It's a nice alternative to using mocks and may suit your needs in some scenarios. It's built on top of [Kestrel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-5.0) (and yes, I'm the author).

Answer (score 3):

All you need is a test version of `HttpMessageHandler` class which you pass to `HttpClient` ctor. The main point is that your test `HttpMessageHandler` class will have a `HttpRequestHandler` delegate that the callers can set and simply handle the `HttpRequest` the way they want.

```
public class FakeHttpMessageHandler : HttpMessageHandler
    {
        public Func<HttpRequestMessage, CancellationToken, HttpResponseMessage> HttpRequestHandler { get; set; } =
        (r, c) => 
            new HttpResponseMessage
            {
                ReasonPhrase = r.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri,
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK
            };


        protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(HttpRequestHandler(request, cancellationToken));
        }
    }
```

You can use an instance of this class to create a concrete HttpClient instance. Via the HttpRequestHandler delegate you have full control over outgoing http requests from HttpClient.

Answer (score 3):

After carefully searching, I figured out the best approach to accomplish this.

```
    private HttpResponseMessage response;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        var handlerMock = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>();

        handlerMock
           .Protected()
           .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>(
              "SendAsync",
              ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(),
              ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
           // This line will let you to change the response in each test method
           .ReturnsAsync(() => response);

        _httpClient = new HttpClient(handlerMock.Object);

        yourClinet = new YourClient( _httpClient);
    }
```

> As you noticed I have used Moq and Moq.Protected packages.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but I feel the urge to extend the answers with a solution I didn't see here.
You can fake the Microsoft assemly (System.Net.Http) and then use ShinsContext during the test.

1. In VS 2017, right click on the System.Net.Http assembly and choose "Add Fakes Assembly"
2. Put your code in the unit test method under a ShimsContext.Create() using. This way, you can isolate the code where you are planning to fake the HttpClient.
3. Depends on your implementation and test, I would suggest to implement all the desired acting where you call a method on the HttpClient and want to fake the returned value. Using ShimHttpClient.AllInstances will fake your implementation in all the instances created during your test. For example, if you want to fake the GetAsync() method, do the following:

   ```
   [TestMethod]
   public void FakeHttpClient()
   {
       using (ShimsContext.Create())
       {
           System.Net.Http.Fakes.ShimHttpClient.AllInstances.GetAsyncString = (c, requestUri) =>
           {
             //Return a service unavailable response
             var httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable);
             var task = Task.FromResult(httpResponseMessage);
             return task;
           };

           //your implementation will use the fake method(s) automatically
           var client = new Connection(_httpClient);
           client.doSomething(); 
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Since `HttpClient` use `SendAsync` method to perform all `HTTP Requests`, you can `override SendAsync` method and mock the `HttpClient`.

For that wrap creating `HttpClient` to a `interface`, something like below

```
public interface IServiceHelper
{
    HttpClient GetClient();
}
```

Then use above `interface` for dependency injection in your service, sample below

```
public class SampleService
{
    private readonly IServiceHelper serviceHelper;

    public SampleService(IServiceHelper serviceHelper)
    {
        this.serviceHelper = serviceHelper;
    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(int dummyParam)
    {
        try
        {
            var dummyUrl = "http://www.dummyurl.com/api/controller/" + dummyParam;
            var client = serviceHelper.GetClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(dummyUrl);               

            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // log.
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Now in unit test project create a helper class for mocking `SendAsync`. 
Here it is a `FakeHttpResponseHandler` class which is `inheriting` `DelegatingHandler` which will provide an option to override the `SendAsync` method. After overriding the `SendAsync` method need to setup a response for each `HTTP Request` which is calling `SendAsync` method, for that create a `Dictionary` with `key` as `Uri` and `value` as `HttpResponseMessage` so that whenever there is a `HTTP Request` and if the `Uri` matches `SendAsync` will return the configured `HttpResponseMessage`.

```
public class FakeHttpResponseHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly IDictionary<Uri, HttpResponseMessage> fakeServiceResponse;
    private readonly JavaScriptSerializer javaScriptSerializer;
    public FakeHttpResponseHandler()
    {
        fakeServiceResponse =  new Dictionary<Uri, HttpResponseMessage>();
        javaScriptSerializer =  new JavaScriptSerializer();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Used for adding fake httpResponseMessage for the httpClient operation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TQueryStringParameter"> query string parameter </typeparam>
    /// <param name="uri">Service end point URL.</param>
    /// <param name="httpResponseMessage"> Response expected when the service called.</param>
    public void AddFakeServiceResponse(Uri uri, HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage)
    {
        fakeServiceResponse.Remove(uri);
        fakeServiceResponse.Add(uri, httpResponseMessage);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Used for adding fake httpResponseMessage for the httpClient operation having query string parameter.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TQueryStringParameter"> query string parameter </typeparam>
    /// <param name="uri">Service end point URL.</param>
    /// <param name="httpResponseMessage"> Response expected when the service called.</param>
    /// <param name="requestParameter">Query string parameter.</param>
    public void AddFakeServiceResponse<TQueryStringParameter>(Uri uri, HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage, TQueryStringParameter requestParameter)
    {
        var serilizedQueryStringParameter = javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(requestParameter);
        var actualUri = new Uri(string.Concat(uri, serilizedQueryStringParameter));
        fakeServiceResponse.Remove(actualUri);
        fakeServiceResponse.Add(actualUri, httpResponseMessage);
    }

    // all method in HttpClient call use SendAsync method internally so we are overriding that method here.
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if(fakeServiceResponse.ContainsKey(request.RequestUri))
        {
            return Task.FromResult(fakeServiceResponse[request.RequestUri]);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        {
            RequestMessage = request,
            Content = new StringContent("Not matching fake found")
        });
    }
}
```

Create a new implementation for `IServiceHelper` by mocking framework or like below. 
This `FakeServiceHelper` class we can use to inject the `FakeHttpResponseHandler` class so that whenever the `HttpClient` created by this `class` it will use `FakeHttpResponseHandler class` instead of the actual implementation.

```
public class FakeServiceHelper : IServiceHelper
{
    private readonly DelegatingHandler delegatingHandler;

    public FakeServiceHelper(DelegatingHandler delegatingHandler)
    {
        this.delegatingHandler = delegatingHandler;
    }

    public HttpClient GetClient()
    {
        return new HttpClient(delegatingHandler);
    }
}
```

And in test configure `FakeHttpResponseHandler class` by adding the `Uri` and expected `HttpResponseMessage`. 
The `Uri` should be the actual `service`endpoint `Uri` so that when the `overridden SendAsync` method is called from actual `service` implementation it will match the `Uri` in `Dictionary` and respond with the configured `HttpResponseMessage`.
After configuring inject the `FakeHttpResponseHandler object` to the fake `IServiceHelper` implementation.
Then inject the `FakeServiceHelper class` to the actual service which will make the actual service to use the `override SendAsync` method.

```
[TestClass]
public class SampleServiceTest
{
    private FakeHttpResponseHandler fakeHttpResponseHandler;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        fakeHttpResponseHandler = new FakeHttpResponseHandler();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task GetMethodShouldReturnFakeResponse()
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.dummyurl.com/api/controller/");
        const int dummyParam = 123456;
        const string expectdBody = "Expected Response";

        var expectedHttpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new StringContent(expectdBody)
        };

        fakeHttpResponseHandler.AddFakeServiceResponse(uri, expectedHttpResponseMessage, dummyParam);

        var fakeServiceHelper = new FakeServiceHelper(fakeHttpResponseHandler);

        var sut = new SampleService(fakeServiceHelper);

        var response = await sut.Get(dummyParam);

        var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
        Assert.AreEqual(expectdBody, responseBody);
    }
}
```

[GitHub Link : which is having sample implementation](https://github.com/dotnet-arun-ghosh/tdd-faking-httpclient)

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Thank you @БогданОпир for feedback updated explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I did something very simple, as I was in a DI environment.

```
public class HttpHelper : IHttpHelper
{
    private ILogHelper _logHelper;

    public HttpHelper(ILogHelper logHelper)
    {
        _logHelper = logHelper;
    }

    public virtual async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAsync(string uri, Dictionary<string, string> headers = null)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response;
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            if (headers != null)
            {
                foreach (var h in headers)
                {
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(h.Key, h.Value);
                }
            }
            response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
        }

        return response;
    }

    public async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string uri, Dictionary<string, string> headers = null)
    {
        ...

        rawResponse = await GetAsync(uri, headers);

        ...
    }

}
```

and the mock is:

```
    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
       ...
        _httpHelper = new Mock<HttpHelper>(_logHelper.Object) { CallBase = true };
       ...
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task SuccessStatusCode_WithAuthHeader()
    {
        ...

        _httpHelper.Setup(m => m.GetAsync(_uri, myHeaders)).Returns(
            Task<HttpResponseMessage>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                return new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_testData))
                };
            })
        );
        var result = await _httpHelper.Object.GetAsync<TestDTO>(...);

        Assert.AreEqual(...);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [PointZeroTwo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44028625/1089267), here's a sample using [NUnit](https://nunit.org/) and [FakeItEasy](https://fakeiteasy.github.io/).

`SystemUnderTest` in this example is the class that you want to test - no sample content given for it but I assume you have that already!

```
[TestFixture]
public class HttpClientTests
{
    private ISystemUnderTest _systemUnderTest;
    private HttpMessageHandler _mockMessageHandler;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _mockMessageHandler = A.Fake<HttpMessageHandler>();
        var httpClient = new HttpClient(_mockMessageHandler);

        _systemUnderTest = new SystemUnderTest(httpClient);
    }

    [Test]
    public void HttpError()
    {
        // Arrange
        A.CallTo(_mockMessageHandler)
            .Where(x => x.Method.Name == "SendAsync")
            .WithReturnType<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>()
            .Returns(Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage
            {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
                Content = new StringContent("abcd")
            }));

        // Act
        var result = _systemUnderTest.DoSomething();

        // Assert
        // Assert.AreEqual(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: what if I want to pass a parameter to the method, mentioned against "x.Method.Name" ..?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps there would be some code to change in your current project but for new projects you should absolutely consider using Flurl.

https://flurl.dev

It is a HTTP client library for .NET with a fluent interface that specifically enables testability for code that uses it to make HTTP requests.

There are plenty of code samples on the website but in a nutshell you use it like this in your code.

Add the usings.

```
using Flurl;
using Flurl.Http;
```

Send a get request and read the response.

```
public async Task SendGetRequest()
{
   var response = await "https://example.com".GetAsync();
   // ...
}
```

In the unit tests Flurl acts as a mock that can be configured to behave as desired and also to verify the calls that were done.

```
using (var httpTest = new HttpTest())
{
   // Arrange
   httpTest.RespondWith("OK", 200);

   // Act
   await sut.SendGetRequest();

   // Assert
   httpTest.ShouldHaveCalled("https://example.com")
      .WithVerb(HttpMethod.Get);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add my 2 cents. To mock specific http request methods either Get or Post. This worked for me.

```
mockHttpMessageHandler.Protected().Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>("SendAsync", ItExpr.Is<HttpRequestMessage>(a => a.Method == HttpMethod.Get), ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
                                                .Returns(Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage()
                                                {
                                                    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
                                                    Content = new StringContent(""),
                                                })).Verifiable();
```