# Mocking external http calls for API testing in .NET Core

Tags: .net, testing, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to write an API test, kind of end-to-end test, for my application.

Assume that I want to get all `Foo`s in the system. When I hit an endpoint `/foo/all`, I fetch data using `HTTPClient` and get some dependent objects of `Foo` from another microservice `Bar`.

My unit tests are ok. I can also boot [my api for tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/testing/integration-testing) , however I don't want to call `Bar` service as I don't want its dependency on my tests, instead, I want to make something like a stub.

So how can I mock those services? I cannot mock `HttpClient` and override `ConfigureServices` method in my test application bootstrap process, because `HttpClient` does not implement any interface.

Thanks.

Comment: You are not supposed to replace `HttpClient` but your service class which abstracts the `HttpClient`. i.e. `IUserService` and `UserService` which uses the `HttpClient` to perform the calls. In this case instead of injecting `UserService` you mock `IUserService` and register this as dependency. It's tricky since you'd have to do the replacements after `IServiceCollection` has been populated, but before `IServiceProvider` was created (usually between `ConfigureServices` and  `Configure` method)

Comment: For ASP.NET Core, you might want to take a look at this document which has a section on unit testing controllers with an example using POST https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/testing

Comment: @Tseng Yes I can mock my service that uses HttpClient, however this time I cannot test inside of that method. For example in `GetAllUsers()` in `UserService` can make an http call to another microservice, but can also add some logic before passing it back. So do you mean the UserService is not like a domain model, but something like anti corruption layer?

Comment: @Svek thanks for your response but I already implemented controller unit tests. I just want something like end to end tests, starting from controller, visiting the test db and returning back.

Comment: Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36427274/5112433

Comment: Yes definetely looking for something like that, thanks @IlyaChumakov