# How to Mock HttpClient using NSubstitute

Tags: c#, unit-testing, httpclient, virtual, nsubstitute

I am trying to use [NSubstitute](https://nsubstitute.github.io/) to mock HttpClient. Here's the code:

```
public static HttpClient GetHttpClient(bool isSucess = true, string methodType = "GET")
        {
            var mockIHttpMessageHandler = Substitute.For<IMockHttpMessageHandler>();
            var mockHttpMessageHandler = Substitute.For<MockHttpMessageHandler>(mockIHttpMessageHandler);
            var httpResponse = Substitute.For<HttpResponseMessage>();
            httpResponse.Content = new StringContent("\"test\"");
            if (isSucess)
                httpResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
            else
                httpResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;

            var mockHttpClient = Substitute.For<HttpClient>(mockHttpMessageHandler);
            mockHttpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost");

            if(methodType != "POST"){
                mockHttpClient.GetAsync(Arg.Any<Uri>()).ReturnsForAnyArgs(httpResponse);
            }
            return mockHttpClient;
        }
```

However, I got an error at this line:

```
mockHttpClient.GetAsync(Arg.Any<Uri>()).ReturnsForAnyArgs(httpResponse);
```

And the error is

> NSubstitute.Exceptions.RedundantArgumentMatcherException: 'Some
> argument specifications (e.g. Arg.Is, Arg.Any) were left over after
> the last call.
>
> This is often caused by using an argument spec with a call to a member
> NSubstitute does not handle (such as a non-virtual member or a call to
> an instance which is not a substitute), or for a purpose other than
> specifying a call (such as using an arg spec as a return value). For
> example:
>
> ```
> var sub = Substitute.For<SomeClass>();
> var realType = new MyRealType(sub);
> // INCORRECT, arg spec used on realType, not a substitute:
> realType.SomeMethod(Arg.Any<int>()).Returns(2);
> // INCORRECT, arg spec used as a return value, not to specify a call:
> sub.VirtualMethod(2).Returns(Arg.Any<int>());
> // INCORRECT, arg spec used with a non-virtual method:
> sub.NonVirtualMethod(Arg.Any<int>()).Returns(2);
> // CORRECT, arg spec used to specify virtual call on a substitute:
> sub.VirtualMethod(Arg.Any<int>()).Returns(2);
> ```
>
> To fix this make sure you only use argument specifications with calls
> to substitutes. If your substitute is a class, make sure the member is
> virtual.
>
> Another possible cause is that the argument spec type does not match
> the actual argument type, but code compiles due to an implicit cast.
> For example, Arg.Any() was used, but Arg.Any() was
> required.
>
> NOTE: the cause of this exception can be in a previously executed
> test. Use the diagnostics below to see the types of any redundant arg
> specs, then work out where they are being created.
>
> Diagnostic information:
>
> Remaining (non-bound) argument specifications:
> any Uri
>
> All argument specifications:
> any Uri

Are they suggesting I need to change the `getAsync` method? There's no virtual method for `GetAsync`

Edit:

I have also tried to remove NSubstitute for HttpClient as follows, but I still got the same error:

```
public static HttpClient GetHttpClient(bool isSucess = true, string methodType = "GET")
            {
                var mockIHttpMessageHandler = Substitute.For<IMockHttpMessageHandler>();
                var mockHttpMessageHandler = Substitute.For<MockHttpMessageHandler>(mockIHttpMessageHandler);
                var httpResponse = Substitute.For<HttpResponseMessage>();
                httpResponse.Content = new StringContent("\"test\"");
                if (isSucess)
                    httpResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
                else
                    httpResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
    
                 var httpClient = new HttpClient(mockHttpMessageHandler);
                httpClient = new Uri("http://localhost");
    
                if(methodType != "POST"){
                    httpClient .GetAsync(Arg.Any<Uri>()).ReturnsForAnyArgs(httpResponse);
                }
                return httpClient 
            }
```

Comment: all the calls GET POST etc invoke the `Send` method. I would however suggest no mocking httpclient. use an actual httpclient. mock the handler (which the client calls) and let it handle the request.

Comment: Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/36427274/5233410

Comment: @Nkosi thanks, I have tried it without using NSubstitute but I  got the same error

Comment: Try adding the [NSubstitute.Analyzers](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/nsubstitute-analysers/) package to your test project. It might be able to pick up the cause of this.

Answer (score 22):

I appreciate this is an old(ish) question, but it's at the top of the Google Search results for "c# mock httpclient using nsubstitute" today, so I figured an answer would be useful.

First we need to create a mock implemenation of `HttpMessageHandler`. As you can see, we're overriding the protected `SendAsync()` method and exposing its body via our public `Send()` method.

```
public class MockHttpMessageHandler : HttpMessageHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Send(request, cancellationToken);
    }

    public virtual Task<HttpResponseMessage> Send(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Next we need to set up our mocks. Note that I'm using `Substitute.ForPartsOf<T>` instead of `Substitute.For<T>`.

```
var mockHttpMessageHandler = Substitute.ForPartsOf<MockHttpMessageHandler>();
var httpClient = new HttpClient(mockHttpMessageHandler);
```

Finally, we can now use NSubstitute to intercept the call to `Send()` on our handler, which is called by the `HttpClient` for every request, and return our mocked `HttpResponseMessage` back via the client.

```
var mockResponse = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

mockHttpMessageHandler.Send(Arg.Any<AnyHttpRequestMessage>(), Arg.Any<CancellationToken>())
   .Returns(mockResponse);

var result = await httpClient.GetAsync<string>("https://tempuri.org");
```

### Edit for .NET 6

As .NET 6 introduces a `protected virtual Send()` method to the `HttpMessageHandler` class (which will also need overriding if you're using the synchronous `HttpClient` calls), some modifications are required to our `MockHttpMessageHandler`:

```
public class MockHttpMessageHandler : HttpMessageHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(MockSend(request, cancellationToken));
    }

    protected override HttpResponseMessage Send(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return MockSend(request, cancellationToken);
    }

    public virtual HttpResponseMessage MockSend(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: In dotnet 6 there is now a `protected virtual Send()` method so this no longer works as written.

Comment: As this is written it does not work: We get a "access protection" error for the mockHttpMessageHandler.Send !!  
If we use mockHttpMessageHandler.MockSend , we get
"Can not return value of type Task`1 for MockHttpMessageHandler.MockSend (expected..."

Comment: @GregJF it sounds like you're attempting to call the `MockHttpMessageHandler` directly rather than using it in conjunction with a `HttpClient` instance.