# How to test a GraphQLHttpClient in C# with NSubtitute

Tags: c#, unit-testing, graphql, nunit, nsubstitute

i'm doing unit test with NUnit and NSubstitue at the project which uses a GraphQL for an API. The Client of GraphQL is an object and I try it to mock but I don't know how.

I have a Handler to override SensAsync

```
protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return await Task.FromResult(_mockResponse);
}
```

Is there a way to easily mock the object GraphQLHttpClient in unit tests?

Answer (score 1):

You can mock an `HttpClient` and `HttpMessageHandler` instances and use them to initialize your `GraphQLHttpClient`. You can check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68688904/how-to-mock-httpclient-using-nsubstitute).

Comment: Still can't mock the GraphQLClient because is a method without parameters instance the object like: GraphQLHttpClient graphQLClient = await GetGraphQLHttpClient();

Comment: The `GraphQLHttpClient` has a [constructor](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-client/blob/fbf37dfff2830e36a45296079bac27ec60fad550/src/GraphQL.Client/GraphQLHttpClient.cs#L66) that takes three parameters, including an `HttpClient` instance. Another option is to [mock](https://graphql-aspnet.github.io/docs/development/unit-testing) the GraphQL server itself.