# c# unit test httpclient postasync

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nunit, rhino-mocks

I am very new to Testing. I am trying to understand how can I unit test since I do not really need to actually trigger these services but probably mock every step.

How can I unit test the following piece of code?

```
public void myFunction()
{
// I am getting an auth token from a service
// then 

    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
    // do a POST call on another service
    var response = httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);
    }

}
```

Comment: That code is wrong because you're creating a new instance of `HttpClient`.

Comment: See [You're using HttpClient wrong and it is destabilizing your software](https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) and the follow-up [You're (probably still) using HttpClient wrong and it is destabilizing your software](https://josef.codes/you-are-probably-still-using-httpclient-wrong-and-it-is-destabilizing-your-software/) for more info.

Comment: that is not the test code.

Comment: It not being test code makes it worse. And using `HttpClient` the correct way would allow you to to inject one with a mocked handler, allowing you to unit test it.

Comment: @Llama any example i can refer to?

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36425008/mocking-httpclient-in-unit-tests)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Non-overridable members (here: HttpClient.PostAsync) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.

I also tried to mock the HttpClient the same way you did, and I got the same error message.

Non-overridable members (here: HttpClient.PostAsync) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.

I also tried to mock the HttpClient the same way you did, and I got the same error message.

**Solution:
Instead of mocking the HttpClient, mock the HttpMessageHandler.**

Then give the

> mockHttpMessageHandler.Object

to your HttpClient, which you then pass to your product code class. This works because HttpClient uses HttpMessageHandler under the hood:

```
// Arrange
var mockHttpMessageHandler = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>();
mockHttpMessageHandler.Protected()
    .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>("SendAsync", ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(), ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
    .ReturnsAsync(new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK });

var client = new HttpClient(mockHttpMessageHandler.Object);
this._iADLS_Operations = new ADLS_Operations(client);
```

Note: You will also need a

```
using Moq.Protected;
```

at the top of your test file.

Then you can call your method that uses PostAsync from your test, and PostAsync will return an HTTP status OK response:

```
var returnedItem = this._iADLS_Operations.MethodThatUsesPostAsync(/*parameter(s) here*/);
```

Advantage: Mocking HttpMessageHandler means that you don't need extra classes in your product code or your test code.

Helpful resources:

---

https://chrissainty.com/unit-testing-with-httpclient/

---

https://gingter.org/2018/07/26/how-to-mock-httpclient-in-your-net-c-unit-tests/

Answer (score 1):

After mock arrangements can be verify with

```
mockHttpMessageHandler.Protected().Verify("SendAsync", Times.Once(), ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(), ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>());
```