# How to unit test static readonly HttpClient?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, nunit-3.0, .net-4.7

I'd like to unit test the following class.

How can I mock the `HttpClient` when it's used as a `static readonly` field in a static class?

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36425008/mocking-httpclient-in-unit-tests) doesn't help as the OP is using an instance field for the `HttpClient`.

Here's my class:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Integration.IdentityProvider
{
    public static class IdentityProviderApiCaller
    {
        private static readonly HttpClient HttpClient;

        static IdentityProviderApiCaller()
        {
            HttpClient = HttpClientFactory.Create();
            HttpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://someApi.com");
            HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
        }

        public static async Task<IList<AddGroupResult>> AddGroups(AddGroup[] addGroupsModel)
        {
            var content = GetContent(addGroupsModel);
            var urlPath = "/groups";

            var result = await HttpClient.PutAsync(urlPath, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
            return await GetObject<IList<AddGroupResult>>(result).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        private static async Task<T> GetObject<T>(HttpResponseMessage result) where T : class
        {
            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return await DeserializeObject<T>(result.Content).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            var errorResult = await DeserializeObject<ErrorResult>(result.Content).ConfigureAwait(false);
            throw new Exception(errorResult.ExceptionMessage);
        }

        private static async Task<T> DeserializeObject<T>(HttpContent content) where T : class
        {
            var jsonContent = await content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            T obj;
            try
            {
                obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonContent);
            }
            catch (JsonSerializationException)
            {
                return await Task.FromResult<T>(null).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            return obj;
        }

        private static StringContent GetContent<T>(T obj)
        {
            var payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
            var content = new StringContent(payload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            return content;
        }
    }

    public class AddGroup
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

    public class AddGroupResult
    {
        public bool IsSuccessful { get; set; }
    }

    public class ErrorResult
    {
        public string ExceptionMessage { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to post this on code review - there are several issues IMHO, which when addressed, will allow you to test things. There is no separation of concern, verbs are used as a class (maybe better as a method), and I'd remove statics from here as behaviour feels to belong to an instance rather than a type.

Comment: @oleksii The OP took your suggested and posted this question with no modifications on Code Review. We do not answer how to questions there. If you would like to perform a code review on the code [here is the question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/285359/how-would-you-make-this-unit-testable). Right now the question is pretty much off-topic on code review at least until the title changes.

Comment: Hey David, sorry this didn't work out, I would have hoped people will be able to suggest changes. Let me try making a few suggestions here, and see if any of those will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to test things, I will suggest a few changes.

1. Remove all `static` keyword from your code. I understand you would like to have *one* thing that does the job, but this can be achieved by having only one *instance* of the class. This also means it is easier to test your class - create a new instance for a test. You could restrict how many instances is created during the configuration/setup stage in aspnet core (if you are using that).
2. Change the constructor from static to instance *and* pass the client as a dependency to it. The new ctor will look something like this:

```
private readonly HttpClient _client;

public IdentityProviderApiCaller(HttpClient client)
{
    if (client == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(client));
    _client = client
}
```

The key point here, is that you provide the dependency of `IdentityProviderApiCaller` in a ctor, so you can unit test it. In a unit test you provide a `mock` for the HTTP client, so you can set expectation for `get` or `post` and see if the method is being called correctly. In an `integration` test you can pass a real instance of HTTP client, so you can actually hit your back end services.

3. Clarify arguments to the function, consider passing a simple list/array. If you rename the `AddGroup` class to a `Group`, then the code gets easier to read. Imagine you can also have APIs to `Delete(Group group)` or list groups. Having a name `AddGroup` for the group will be confusing. Also, you can simplify the the `async`. So all together the code should look something like:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> AddGroups(List<Group> groups)
{
    if (groups == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(groups));
    var content = GetContent(addGroupsModel);
    var urlPath = "/groups";
    return await _client.PutAsync(urlPath, content);
}
```

4. Throw a more focused exception, the class `Exception` is very broad. Consider common exceptions `ArgumentException`, `InvalidOperationException`, etc. You could create your own exception too, but maybe best check what built-in exceptions are available

```
throw new Exception(errorResult.ExceptionMessage); // so this line can become a more focused exception
```

There may be a class, specifically for aspnet core, where you can return a failure code, it may look something like:

```
return BadRequest(errorResult.ExceptionMessage);
```

The idea is that you can specify which error code is returned to the client of your API, such as 401, 400. If an exception is thrown, I think it will be status code 500 Internal Server error, which may not be ideal for the client of the API

---

Now, back to the unit testing, in *meta-code*, this is how it will look:

```
[TestFixture]
public class IdentityProviderApiCallerTest
{
    private readonly IdentityProviderApiCaller _uut; // unit under test

    [Test]
    public void AddGroups()
    {
        var mock = Mock<HttpClient>.Create(); // syntax depends on the mock lib
        mock.Expect(x => x.Put(...)); // configure expectations for calling HTTP PUT
        _uut = new IdentityProviderApiCaller(mock) // this is how you pass the dependency
        var group = new Group();
        var result = _uut.AddGroups(group);
        assert.True(result.IsSuccessful)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Oleksii's advice is on point: inject the HttpClient in order to make it unit testable. But there are a few more things to say on the subject of HttpClient.

Set up your dependency injection to [use IHttpClientFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) to give you HttpClients, to avoid socket contention and stale DNS issues.

HttpClient itself is a thin and straightforward wrapper around HttpMessageHandler. Instead of mocking HttpClient, you'll want to mock HttpMessageHandler, and pass it into an actual HttpClient instance. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/36427274/120955