# How can I simulate a 404 error for testing two connected Web API services in ASP.NET Core 7?

Tags: asp.net, testing, .net-core, integration

Let's say I have two ASP.NET Core 7 Web APIs. One gets and uses a value from the other one by sending a request.

**1) Sensor API** that returns a random int between 0-100:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class TrafficSensorController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet(Name = "GetTrafficSensor")]
    public int Get()
    {
        return new Random().Next(100);
    }
}
```

**2) Report API** that requests to the Sensor API and returns a string representation of the integer value:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class TrafficReportController : ControllerBase
{
    private static readonly string SENSOR_URL = "https://localhost:7272/TrafficSensor";

    [HttpGet(Name = "GetTrafficReport")]
    public async Task<string> Get()
    {
        var response = await new HttpClient().GetAsync(SENSOR_URL);

        string report = "ERROR!";

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            int sensorValue = int.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

            if (sensorValue < 30)
                report = "LIGHT TRAFFIC";
            else if (sensorValue < 70)
                report = "MODERATE TRAFFIC";
            else
                report = "HEAVY TRAFFIC";
        }

        return report;
    }
}
```

Now, I need to write an integration test to simulate an **unavailable sensor API** that returns 404 or 500 to verify  that the report API returning correct error message in such situation. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, that's probably not how you want to use `HttpClient`. See [Guidelines for using HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/http/httpclient-guidelines)
 or [Are You Using HttpClient in The Right Way?](https://www.rahulpnath.com/blog/are-you-using-httpclient-in-the-right-way/)

If  you had your HttpClient injected, either directly or through an instance of `IHttpClientFactory`, it could be more or less easily mocked to get the desired response (see answers in [Mocking HttpClient in unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36425008/mocking-httpclient-in-unit-tests), or libraries such as [mockhttp](https://github.com/richardszalay/mockhttp)).

However, if you want to strictly simulate an HTTP response without modifying your code to support `HttpClient` response mocking (against what is strongly encouraged above), something you could do is use [WireMock.Net](https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net) to mimic the behavior of the local HTTP api itself.