# How to mock Httpclient inside method using xunit c#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, httpclient, xunit

I am trying to mock Httpclient which is created inside a method with using keyword
Please see the following sample.

```
Public string testmethod(){

Using(Httpclient client = new Httpclient (){
Var content = "some content"
String url = "xxxx"
Client.defaultrequestheader(key,value);
Var response = client.postasync(uri,content)
})
}
```

How can I mock the above most of the scenario  Httpclient is getting initialised at constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating new instance of `HttpCLient` with `new` keyword, introducing hard dependency on said class and this cannot be mocked.

You have some options to mock `HttpClient`, but you need to use `IHttpClientFactory` in order to mock it:

- use DI - so define constructor with `IHttpClientFactory`, that will be injected and use `Create method to get the client,
- pass instance of `IHttpClientFactory` to the method as parameter, and then create the client using it

In both options, you will be able to mock `Create` method - so you can return mocked `HttpClient` from it.

In order to mock the client, refer to code below

```
var mockMessageHandler = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>();
mockMessageHandler.Protected()
    .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>(
        "SendAsync", 
        ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(), 
        ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
    .ReturnsAsync(new HttpResponseMessage 
    {
        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
        Content = new StringContent("test content")
    });
var underTest = new SiteAnalyzer(new HttpClient(mockMessageHandler.Object));
```

Just use appropriate, desired values here:

```
new HttpResponseMessage 
{
    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
    Content = new StringContent("test content")
}
```

For explanation and full discussion see this SO post - [Mocking HttpClient in unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36425008/mocking-httpclient-in-unit-tests).

Comment: Thanks for the reply but above scenario is not for the creating new instance of httpclient in method right?

Comment: @dev Yes, it is violation disabling from unit testing this piece of code.