# How to mock Firebase in C#?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, firebase-realtime-database, xunit

I am trying to unit test some CRUD operations for my WPF project using XUnit framework. I am also using Firebase database to store sensitive user data. I have never encountered with unit testing, I know that I have to mock the database, but there is very little information available.

I have tried the following but I get an error saying: "An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments"

```
[Fact]
public async Task SavePatientDetails_Success()
{
    var firebaseClientMock = new Mock<FirebaseClient>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    var patientService = new PatientService(firebaseClientMock.Object);

    var patient = new Patient
    {
        Id = "123",
        Name = "John",
        Surname = "Doe",
        FatherName = "Mark",
        PatientGender = "Male",
        Dob = new DateTime(2001, 1, 1),
        Address = "John Doe Avenue 1",
        Phone = "+386 123 456 789",
        Email = "john.doe@emailprovider.com"
    };

    var firebaseObject = Activator.CreateInstance(
        typeof(FirebaseObject<Patient>),
        BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
        null,
        new object[] { "Patients/123", patient },
        null);

    firebaseClientMock.Setup(f => f.Child("Patients").PostAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<Patient>(),null)).ReturnsAsync(true);

    var result = await patientService.SavePatientDetails(patient);

    Assert.IsTrue(result);
}
```

Comment: You can't mock a concrete class, you can only mock an interface, but your actual problem here is that PostAsync has one or more optional parameters that you haven't included in your mock.

Comment: That looks like a standard Mocking problem. You must setup all parameters of a method you can't leave away the optional parameters. So take a look if the "Child" or "PostAsync" method have additional parameters. And if then set them also up. You can't leave them out even if you don't use them in your code explicitly.

Comment: This will be a little tricky since `FirebaseClient` doesn't have an interface. But it's possible to create a real `FirebaseClient` with a [mocked `HttpClient`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36427274/1025555). For that you have to use `FirebaseOptions` and set its `HttpClientFactory` property to an implementation that returns an `IHttpClientProxy` wich in turn returns your mocked `HttpClient`. Browse the [source code](https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-database-dotnet/blob/master/src/Firebase/FirebaseClient.cs) for the details.